# Java Slick2D Image Glow Effect

Tags: java, slick, graphic-effects

How can one achieve a dynamic glow effect in Java Slick2d? I want an image to be surrounded by a glow when I move my mouse over it for example.

Example:

[image]
No glow

[image]
Glow

Is it possible to make this programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest just making the image with a glowing effect, but if you must have it done in game then you would:

1) Render your scene or "glow objects" to texture A

2) Bind texture A, then using the horizontal shader, render a quad to texture B

3) Bind texture B, then using the vertical shader, render a quad to texture A

However This requires the following OpenGL extensions:

- GL_ARB_shader_objects or GL20
- GL_EXT_framebuffer_object or GL30

(You can find the full answer on the website below. The guy there explains it better than me)

http://slick.ninjacave.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4923